# OUT param is not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, events

I am having issue. I am talking to api in following form:

`SomeClass variable2;
 SomeClass variable2;
 var result = API.doSomeStaff(variable1, out variable2);`

I am having response from `API.doSomeStaff` before `variable2` param is modified
If I add some `Thread.Sleep(100)` Everything is great. But I dont like this approach so I want to make some event which is fired when `variable2` is modified. And send back modified `variable2`

Could you help me how could I do this with events or with any other suitable options.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. What has `Thread.Sleep(100)` to do with `out` parameter?

Comment: What happends inside the doSomeStaff method?

Comment: @SᴇM I meant that in side the `doSomeStaff` it is processed somehow and is not set synchronously with result, in other words when I have `result.type="success"` `variable2` is still empty I need. What I need is changed `variable2`

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich I dont have access to `doSomeStaff` method

Comment: Your question is not very clear please refer to guide [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) you need to help understand your problem which is not very clear in this post. You need to explain what the `API` you are interacting with does? Also what is your end goal?

Comment: @Kevin Changed, hope it would be clear for you

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Api
{
    public event EventHandler<string> ValueChanged;
    public string SomeMethod(string a)
    {
        //do your logic here, if true then invoke the event
        if (a.Length > 0)
        {
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(EventArgs.Empty, "String length is greater than zero!!!");         
        }
        return a.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

What you need is to implement an event inside your api and call it if some logic occurs and then invoke the event if is not null. It's up to you what kind of datatype of the event, in example above i use string.

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code as text. This isn't useful otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I dont have access to api. I need to listed to `out` parameter change from place I called api method